# Please help me save data sent by the server in response to my cURL GET request

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying learn PHP by actually doing something I may find useful for myself. There is a betting agency in my country which has a website where I can check if I won or not by entering a ticket number. I am trying to write a PHP script to check if range of tickets are worth anything so I don't have to enter every ticket manually on their website.

I managed to do that. But now I want to save the response I get from their server in a file. I  run into serious problems with this. I managed to save the verbose into a file but I am unable to make the script save to a file what I see on the screen inside my browser after running the script.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

function check($week, $base, $startcheck, $endcheck, $verbose = "true"){

// Set file path
$verbosePath = 'publicbet.txt';
echo "Saving the tickets to: <b>$verbosePath</b>\n";

// Initiate numbering
$i = 0;

// Initiate publicbet.ro IP
$ip = "80.86.107.93";

// Loop
while ($startcheck <= $endcheck){

    // Generate tickkey
    $tickkey = $week.$base.$startcheck;

    // get the current server time
    $time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

    // Open a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Stuff
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen($verbosePath, "a"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");

    // publicbet.ro may be checking the IP adress
    // from where the $tickkey is sent in order to
    // check for abnormalities; we will send the
    // IP adress of the website:)
    $headerarray = array(
        "X-Forwarded-For: $ip");

    // Set the URL and other options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://publicbet.ro/gettickinfo2.php?lang=ro&tickkey='.$tickkey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.publicbet.ro/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerarray);

    // Executing cURL
    curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL resource, free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($f);

    // Showing informtion
    $v .= "<br />$i. At <b>$time</b> the server checked the tickkey: <b>$tickkey</b> and returned the tickket: ";
    if ($verbose == "true"){
        echo $v;
        $v = '';
    }

// Modifying values
$startcheck++;
$i++;

}

}

if ($_POST[week] && $_POST[base] && $_POST[startcheck] && $_POST[endcheck]){
check($_POST[week], $_POST[base], $_POST[startcheck], $_POST[endcheck]);
}
else {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<title>publicbet.ro</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Check your tickets here</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>week:</td>
                <td>base:</td>
                <td>start check:</td>
                <td>end check:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" name="week" min="00" max="54" maxlength="2" size="2" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="base" maxlength="11" size="11" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="startcheck" maxlength="6" size="6" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="endcheck" maxlength="6" size="6" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Check!" />
</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php } ?>
```

So please tell me if there is any method of doing what I am willing to. I would be really pleased.

If you want to test the script use these values:
week: 05
base: 16010234203
start check: 350900
end check: 350920 .

It will return 19 false tickets and 1 true. I want all this text which is showing up to be exported to a text file rather than showing on my screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`, and then where you do `curl_exec()`, assign it to a variable like this:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch)
```

Then you can save it like this:

```
file_put_contents('my_file.txt', $data);
```

Use constants instead of string literals for things like true and false etc.. I see in your function arguments you do `$verbose = "true"`, this could be replaced with `$verbose = true`.

You also are using constants where you should actually be using string literals, for example `$_POST[base]` should be `$_POST['base']` or `$_POST["base"]`

Please don't use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` like that, it leaves you very open to XSS attacks, etc. You can do `action=""` and it will post to the page in question, like `PHP_SELF`

Where you are doing

```
if($_POST[base] .....)
```

I recommend doing this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['base'], $_POST['somethingElse'], $_POST['anotherField'])) {
    // yay
}
```